# Preloading images into the memory cache at application launch, using objective c for iOS

Tags: objective-c

The issue I am having, concerns trying to display thumbnail images in a list of UITableViewCells. I have 200 thumbnails to display.

My app downloads a zip file of images from my remote server, unzips the contents into the NSDocumentDirectory. After an update, which happens once a week, the app then displays the thumbnails using [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]
Once, I know this has been cached, I display the thumbnail using [UIImage imageNamed:]

My problem is that when I display 200 thumbnails using 
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] on the first display event after an update, the app sometimes freezes after a few minutes, saying that too many image files are open.

ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed '/Users/cdesign/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/B458A3F5-5B21-49CD-B4D8-17E5189678FA/Documents/91.png'
error = 24 (Too many open files)

This never happens once the images are cached in memory.

Then, when I try and click on a UITableViewCell to proceed to my 'DetailController', I get the following error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name '9ka-eC-wSa-view-LRp-aI-LGN' and directory 'MainStoryboard.storyboardc''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1bd0012 0x1473e7e 0x1bcfdeb 0x5d3ef9 0x4987e7 0x498dc8 0x5e728e 0x498ff8 0x499232 0x4994da 0x4b08e5 0x4b09cb 0x4b0c76 0x4b0d71 0x4b189b 0x4b1e93 0x4b1a88 0x80de63 0x7ffb99 0x7ffc14 0x467249 0x4674ed 0xe715b3 0x1b8f376 0x1b8ee06 0x1b76a82 0x1b75f44 0x1b75e1b 0x16ef7e3 0x16ef668 0x3b7ffc 0x2a1d 0x2945)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

This is strange, because I do not have a file called 'MainStoryboard.storyboardc'.
My app has no localisation. My project does not even have a 'en.lproj' folder. I only have 'MainStoryboard.storyboard' in the root.

I am not sure if the 2 error are related. Or, if the second error is responsible for the first. This would suggest that there is no issue with my images?

I must say that when I have tested my app, by using a modified 'getImage' method that only returns cached images, the first error disappears but the second error, concerning the 'MainStoryboard.storyboard' does still occur, occasionally, if I leave the app idle for more than a couple of minutes, on the 'ListController' screen.

Both these issues **ONLY** ever occur on the 'ListController' screen. The app always launches successfully to display the 'home' screen. On the home screen there is a link to the 'ListController' screen.

Assuming, though, that the image display is the problem, is there a way to preload images during application launch to preload the newly updated images from the document folder into the memory cache, so that I never have to use 
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] to display images in the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath?

If, this is possible, do I use NSCache to achieve the image preload?

And, if I use NSCache, do files with the same name overwrite entries in NSCache, or do I have to delete files, with the same name, first?

Sorry, for preempting, the answer to my initial question, but this may save time?

1. My app contains a storyboard, called MainStoryboard.storyboard
2. Target device: iPhone 5
3. Xcode version: 4.6.3

Here is some relevant code:

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)hasImageBeenUpdated:(NSString *)postureid{
    BOOL result = NO;
    YTAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.imagesupdated == nil) {
        appDelegate.imagesupdated = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    NSString *imageid = [NSString string];
    for (int i = 0; i < appDelegate.imagesupdated.count; i++) {
        imageid = [appDelegate.imagesupdated objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([imageid isEqualToString: postureid]) {
            result = YES;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


- (UIImage *)getImage:(NSString *)postureid{
    self.nsLogsOn = YES;
    YTAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIImage *result = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",postureid];
    if (self.nsLogsOn) {
        NSLog(@"appDelegate.imagesHaveBeenDownloaded: %i",appDelegate.imagesHaveBeenDownloaded);
    }
    if(!appDelegate.imagesHaveBeenDownloaded){
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];
        if (self.nsLogsOn) {
            NSLog(@"image cached no download: %@",imagePath);
        }
    }
    else{
        if (appDelegate.imagesupdated == nil) {
            appDelegate.imagesupdated = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        BOOL imageHasBeenUpdated = [self hasImageBeenUpdated:postureid];
        if(!imageHasBeenUpdated){
           imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[self documentsFilePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagePath]];
            [appDelegate.imagesupdated addObject:postureid];
            if (self.nsLogsOn) {
                NSLog(@"image download: %@",imagePath);
            }
        }
        else{
           imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];
            if (self.nsLogsOn) {
                NSLog(@"image cached download: %@",imagePath);
            }
        }
    }
    if(imageview.image==nil){
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[self documentsFilePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagePath]];
        if (self.nsLogsOn) {
            NSLog(@"image cache cleared by iOS: %@",imagePath);
        }
    }
    if(imageview.image==nil){
        imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo-lotus-imageview-white-c.png"];
        if (self.nsLogsOn) {
            NSLog(@"image cannot be found: %@",imagePath);
        }
    }
    result = imageview.image;    
    return result;
}
```

ListController.m

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [keys count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [posturegroups objectForKey:key];
    return [nameSection count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    return [key capitalizedString];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = @"plainCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [posturegroups objectForKey:key];
    YTPosture *thePosture = [nameSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    YTAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[YTAppDelegate alloc] init];    
    UIImageView *imageview = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    imageview.image = [appDelegate getImage:thePosture.postureid];
    imageview.backgroundColor = [appDelegate defaultColor];
    UILabel *cellLabel1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    NSString *aStr = [NSString string];
    NSString *bStr = [NSString string];
    NSString *title = [NSString string];
    if([selection valueForKey:@"symptomExists"]){
        aStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",thePosture.memberOrder];
        bStr = thePosture.title;
        title = [aStr stringByAppendingString:bStr];
    }
    else{
        title = thePosture.title;
    }
    cellLabel1.text = title;
    UILabel *cellLabel2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    cellLabel2.text = thePosture.sanskritTransliteration;
    YTKeyController *keyController = [[YTKeyController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *branch = [keyController compileData];
    NSString *branchid = thePosture.branchid;
    NSString *list = @"1.0,1.0,1.0";
    NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@","];    
    for (int i = 0; i < [branch count]; i++) {
        YTBranch *theBranch = [branch objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([branchid isEqualToString:theBranch.branchid]) {
            list = theBranch.key;
            listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
            break;
        }
    }    
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:[[listItems objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] green:[[listItems objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] blue:[[listItems objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] alpha:1]];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Nib name" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelegate:)]) {
        [destination setValue:self forKey:@"delegate"];
    }
    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setSelection:)]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
        NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
        NSArray *nameSection = [posturegroups objectForKey:key];
        YTPosture *thePosture = [nameSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        id object = thePosture;
        NSDictionary *aselection = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   indexPath, @"indexPath",
                                   object, @"object",
                                   nil];
        [destination setValue:aselection forKey:@"selection"];
    }
}
```

Comment: not considered using something like SDWebImage, even just the cache part, SDImageCache? https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage AFNetworking also has image loading. Would save you a lot of pain doing this from scratch

Comment: Max. Thanks for the reply, but I am not entirely sure that it is an image issue or an issue with my app trying to find 'MainStoryboard.storyboardc', which doesn't exist. On the image side of things, I really want to know whether NSCache, loads files into memory. So, if I store the image in NSCache, does it have the same effect as [UIImage imageNamed:]?

Comment: To be honest I know how to quickly write a function that will store images in NSCache, but I want to know if NSCache loads files into memory?

Comment: imageNamed caches automatically

Comment: Yes, but I cannot use imageNamed, for the reasons outlined above. I want to preload images into memory before they are displayed. So, I need to do this programmatically. Do you know if NSCache does the same job?

Comment: From, what I know  [UIImage imageNamed:] can only be used if iOS has put the image into the memory cache, once it has been displayed to the app user.

Comment: There should not be any issues by displaying 200 thumbnails in a UITableView on the fly. Using imageWithContentsOfFile should work as is, without a need to manage memory cache. Have you tried simplifying your code and simply try to get the image with imageWithContentOfFile in tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: [UIImage imageNamed:] loads from the resource bundle and handles caching automatically

Comment: Champoul. That is what I thought. 200 small [40px X 30px] thumbnails should be a breeze. I did do a test where my 'getImage' function, only contained imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[self documentsFilePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagePath]];, but it made no difference. The ListController still froze after a few minutes, then the images disappear. Once the screen freezes, I am able to navigate back to the home screen, but if I try and select a UITableViewCell to go the DetailController, the app crashes.

Comment: It is really strange, how the app works perfectly for a few minutes. I can scroll pretty fast up & down the ListController, successfully select UITableViewCell. The app just seems to lose focus after a few minutes. It is so hard to debug. I have spent days trying to find the issue!!!!

Comment: Champoul.I will try your test, using image with imageWithContentOfFile in tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath:. I will let you know what happens.

Comment: Champoul. Your test makes no difference. Even if i load the image with imageWithContentOfFile in tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath:, after a couple of minutes I get: ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed '/Users/cdesign/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/B458A3F5-5B21-49CD-B4D8-17E5189678FA/Documents/170.png'
         error = 24 (Too many open files)

Comment: Do I have to remove images from the IO in cells, that are being dequeued? But how do I do this?

Comment: this is very weird. you should profile your application with Instruments to see what causes the freeze : this might give you indications of a high memory consuming operation of something like that.

Comment: OK. Champoul. I have a development. I added this to the app launch:

Comment: NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MainStoryboard" withExtension:@"storyboardc"];

Comment: The result: fileURL: file://localhost/Users/cdesign/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/B458A3F5-5B21-49CD-B4D8-17E5189678FA/Yoga%20Therapy.app/MainStoryboard.storyboardc/

Comment: But I do not have this file in my project. What on earth is going on. How do I remove this from my bundle. I am sure this is causing the problem..

Comment: I removed all derived data, any localisation references. I have checked my Target -> Build Phases, and there is no such file? I think Xcode must be adding 'MainStor‌​yboard.storyboardc' when it compiles the app. How do I stop this???????

Comment: NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MainStoryboard" withExtension:@"storyboard"];
NSLog(@"fileURL: %@",fileURL);

OUTPUT:

fileURL: (null)

So, in my bundle, I have a 'MainStoryboard.storyboardc' and no 'MainStoryboard.storyboard'.

But in Xcode, I have 'MainStoryboard.storyboard' and no 'MainStoryboard.storyboardc' in my project directory.

Can anyone explain what the hell is going on?

Comment: this is not related to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have found what the problem was. I feel a little embarrassed!

The first point is that 'MainStoryboard.storyboardc' is meant to be present. The 'c' on the end stands for the compiled version of 'MainStoryboard.storyboard'.

Well, the image issue, was to do with the fact that I was trying to call a method that amongst other things, was compiling an SQLite statement from inside the method below:

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Plus I was also calling another method that was looping through about 200 items from inside the same method.

Effectively, these 2 routines were being run for every UITableViewCell that was scrolling into view.

These two issues were crash and burning the system.

Once I removed these issues I decided to call the images using [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile], without any problems. In fact the 'ListController' now has about 200 thumbnails in it, and it scrolls as smooth as silk.

I feel like a total idiot for wasting your time. Most definitely, I have learnt a big lesson from this. I need to debug & check more thoroughly, and think about every line of code and the context it is written in. In fact, I have learnt that the only information loaded into the method above, should be data that is already indexed.

Champoul's suggestion to use Instruments in Memory Leaks mode, was how I found out the source of this issue. Thanks very much for your help...